# Read programmatically MS Word Doc with client side javaScript

Tags: javascript, web, client, ms-office, webclient

I have been trying to figure out, "how to programmatically read Doc file on client side using javaScript"?

I find just [DOCX.js](https://web.archive.org/web/20161119165232/http://blog.innovatejs.com/?p=184) ([github](https://github.com/stephen-hardy/DOCX.js)) and do not even know, this library can help me or not.

Comment: Just a thought.. If you only want to open a Word file for the user to read and the user has an appropriate application installed, I suggest setting a link to the file. The user will be able to download the file, and the system may automatically open it.

Comment: It isn't exactly what you're looking for but cloud convert has the option to convert .docx to html or text files. And cloud convert does have a JavaScript api. You might also be able to do it through Google's drive api since it supports docx.  For cloud convert look at cloudconvert.com for google drive look at developers.google.com/drive. Aside from those options there is probably a way the problem being that they aren't basic text they are rich text files where JavaScript and web pages run off of basic text

Comment: javascript will read that doc programmaticly..

Comment: @Binvention i m making an questionnaire web app in unity where  Admin will upload his doc file ,this doc file will contains Questions and  user will answer the questions , and tricky part is how doc file will be processed ..

Comment: @Binvention google drive is one of best option, but there are more things to sort like google drive oth , cross domain issues .....etc ..

Comment: But the admin uploading and the user answering are both happening on the client side? And just to be clear are you referring to the .doc extension or Microsoft's current document extension .docx

Comment: Your link to docx js seems to be what you're looking for. Have you tried using it?